# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract' MacOs

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

i am currently trying to use [Pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract), the "python version" of the OCR [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).
I've followed every steps of the installation you can find on the [pytesseract's github](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) and even the step to check if everything is working(running Tesseract from the terminal and installing and launching tox).

But after all of this when I try to run my script

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/users/lucas/desktop/image.png')))
```

I just have the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'` error.
I tried everything I could find linked to this on StackOverflow/Google and nothing is working.

The script is running from a folder on my desktop.
MacOS 13.4.1
Python 3.9.0

Everything I found on google :

- launching from a python3 -v -m my script
- reinstalling pytesseract

Comment: Could it be a case that you have installed the pytasseract in a virtual environment ? and try to execute the script out of that virtual environment.

Comment: No have no virtual environnement, I have one user and one OS on this machine, nothing complicated.

Answer (score -1):

1. pytessertact is just a python wrap of  Google's Tesseract-OCR Engine, you need install the tesseract before run python code https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#installation
2. according to  https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html
   you can install tessertact on mac with

   brew install tesseract

then everything goes well. I have reproduce the error and after install tesseract, it can runs successfully.

Comment: Of course all of that is already done, I wouldn't have come here to ask the question